# iphones inbuilt mail composer

Tags: iphone

Hello everyone i am new to i phone development i have a requirement that my email us field is coming from webservice on tapping it the iphones email composer gets open if i want to add a button on iphones in built mail composer i could i do that please guide me to do that a sample code would be a boost

Answer (score 1):

MFMailComposeViewController is a view controller so you can add views to the view it controls.

```
UIButton extraButton = [UIButton ...];
[mailComposer.view addSubview:extraButton];
```

To make it look good may be a little more difficult.